# Guice cannot instantiate class that extends JPanel - NPE in call to super constructor

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, classloader, guice

We have a desktop Swing application with Google Guice 4.1.0 dependency injection. Everything worked fine during development, but something strange happened when colleague tried to run the application.

We have a `MainWindow` class that extends `JPanel`. In the constructor this class takes some controllers that itself are injectable. In main method Guice injector is created. Then the injector tries to instantiate `MainWindow` (`injector.getInstance(MainWindow.class)`). And it failed with `NullPointerException`!

This doesn't happen on my computer, and we use the same JDK.

Here is `MainWindow` class stripped down to problematic code (note: this does not reproduce the problem, unfortunately):

```
class MainWindow extends JPanel {
    private final Foo foo;

    private final JFrame frame;

    @Inject
    public MainWindow(Foo foo) {
        super(new GridBagLayout()); // <-- NullPointerException
        this.foo = foo;
        this.frame = new JFrame("title");
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        // ...
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And here is `main()` method:

```
class Main {
    private static final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow mainWindow = injector.getInstance(MainWindow.class);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mainWindow.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is stack trace of the exception:

```
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException
  at app.gui.MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.java:133)
  while locating app.gui.MainWindow

1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1028) ~[app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1054) ~[app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at app.Main.createAndShowGUI(Main.java:40) ~[app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at app.Main.access$000(Main.java:26) ~[app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at app.Main$2.run(Main.java:67) ~[app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
```

The NPE was thrown in the most surprising place – in the call to constructor of superclass of `MainWindow` (this is line 133). I started digging and found out that manual creation of `MainWindow` and injecting its dependencies works correctly:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(injector.getInstance(Foo.class));
```

I suspected that maybe class loader didn't work correctly, so I tried again with logging classloader of both `MainWindow` and `JPanel`:

```
System.out.println("MainWindow: " + MainWindow.class.getClassLoader());
System.out.println("JPanel:     " + JPanel.class.getClassLoader());
MainWindow mainWindow = injector.getInstance(MainWindow.class);
```

Class loaders are different (`JPanel` is loaded by bootstrap), but now the injection worked properly. I suppose this is because now `JPanel` class was explicitly loaded into main method context.

So my questions are:

1. Did anyone have similar problem?
2. Is it my mistake, or is it a bug?
3. If it is a bug, does it happen in Guice? Or maybe JRE?

---

More details about Java and OS:

- I originally developed it with JDK 1.8.0u111, but then switched to JDK 1.8.0u121.
- Application is compiled to Java 6.
- Runs flawlessly on my computer with Windows 10, version 1607 (OS Build 14393.693), on JRE 6 and JRE 8 (from JDK).
- `NullPointerException` is raised on colleague's computer with Windows 10, version 1511 (OS Build 10586.753), JDK 1.8.0u112 and 1.8.0u121.

Unfortunately I was unable to provide minimal version that reproduces the problem. Heck, I cannot even reproduce the problem, it happens only on colleague's environment.

Comment: Have you looked into Guice configuration files? Are there any differences between yours and colleague's?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov There are no differences. Project is built from Maven and no additional configuration is added. What's more, it is a runtime failure, not compilation. Exactly the same JAR works on my computer, but not on his. It doesn't matter if it was compiled by me or him.

Comment: Well, if classloaders are different, then it sure is a runtime problem. Are both machines have different classloaders reported by that log statement? Is there anything printed while injector is called?

Comment: On both machines JPanel class loader returns `null`. As for MainWindow, I get `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@40affc70`, he gets `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@42a57993`.

Comment: They look like they are the same, unless their hierarchy is different. Can you please attach your exception trace then, the part where it fails specifically? I'm not really qualified to answer about Maven configs'n'stuff, but exception log will definitely be helpful.

Comment: Updated the question with stacktrace.

Comment: First of all, you should be injecting `GridLayout` as well. It just defeats the purpose of DI when you have to instantiate an object in the implementation. Also, could you also post the module with the bindings and providers?

Comment: @Nektie I can't disagree more with "It just defeats the purpose of DI when you have to instantiate an object in the implementation." There are plenty of objects—data objects, UI elements, etc—which take no DI-provided dependencies and for which there is no reasonable alternative implementation (including mocks) to provide.

Comment: @Archie Do you override `setLayout`, `setDoubleBuffered`, `setUIProperty`, `updateUI`, `setLocale`, `enableEvents`, or any other system call in `MainWindow`? JPanel [makes some calls to overridable methods in its constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JPanel.java#82), which mean that subclasses can read non-nullable final fields that haven't been set yet. (Separately, I'm surprised you can get away with calling `show` on a parentless JPanel, as opposed to a JFrame or other explicitly top-level component.)

Comment: I respectfully disagree. If you are using a DI framework then you should have a single point of delivery of dependencies regardless if you can or cannot provide mock or alternative implemations of them. It makes the code easier to trace and more modular.

Comment: @JeffBowman — No, no method is overriden in `MainWindow`. Abouth `show()`: sorry, I edited the snippet wrongly. Actually the method that is called is `mainWindow.createAndShowGUI()` which is implemented in `MainWindow`. It does not override `JPanel::show()` method.

Comment: @JeffBowman — I've just updated the code snippet in the question.

Comment: I had the same problem, but with Swing (no GUICE) and Spring Boot. I corrected the problem by: 1. Calling `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");` prior to the EDT runnable, in place of your declaration of MainWindow. 2. Moving the injection in the EDT runnable and calling, in your case: `injector.getInstance(MainWindow.class).createAndShowGUI();`. Not sure it helps though, but you might try.

Comment: Are you or your coworker able to replicate the issue on any other hardware? If it's strictly limited to their machine, and you're not able to replicate it on other machines with the same source and JDK it sounds like some sort of problem with that specific machine.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suspect this is due to a race condition. Swing components are not thread safe and should be instantiated on the EDT as per the [swing package javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading) :

> Swing's Threading Policy
>
> In general Swing is not thread safe. All Swing components and related
>   classes, unless otherwise documented, must be accessed on the event
>   dispatching thread. Typical Swing applications do processing in
>   response to an event generated from a user gesture. For example,
>   clicking on a JButton notifies all ActionListeners added to the
>   JButton. As all events generated from a user gesture are dispatched on
>   the event dispatching thread, most developers are not impacted by the
>   restriction.
>
> **Where the impact lies, however, is in constructing and showing a Swing
>   application.** Calls to an application's main method, or methods in
>   Applet, are not invoked on the event dispatching thread. **As such, care
>   must be taken to transfer control to the event dispatching thread when
>   constructing and showing an application or applet.** The preferred way
>   to transfer control and begin working with Swing is to use
>   invokeLater. The invokeLater method schedules a Runnable to be
>   processed on the event dispatching thread.

*(emphasis mine)*

Now you do start the UI in the EDT, using `invokeLater`, however you construct the UI on the main thread (through a Guice injector call).
The Guice injector call should also be in the `invokeLater` part to kick off the UI.